# Set span-element around text

Tags: jquery

i have an unsorted List like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>NAVIone</li>
    <li>NAVItwo</li>
</ul>
```

I would now that is after the first 4 sign a span around the rest set, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>NAVI<span>one</span></li>
    <li>NAVI<span>two</span></li>
</ul>
```

how can i do that??

Comment: You forgot to post what you tried. Also, what does "I would now that is after the first 4 sign" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `slice`, but having to do this just feels terrible.

```
$('li').html(function (i, html){
  return html.slice(0,4) + '<span>' + html.slice(4) + '</span>';
});
```

Here it is in action: http://jsbin.com/juhoz/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yes, using `attr` setter is the way to go. )